# Create a JWTBearer middleware on FastAPI

Tags: python, jwt, fastapi

I'm trying to make a middleware to check on each route of my FastAPI app if user is connected (JWT).
i.e. I try to make all the routes in the application have an authentication check except some that I could specify by hand at the time of their creation...

I tried many things like :

```
class JWTBearer:
    def __init__(self, app=None, auto_error=True):
        self.app = app
        self.auth_scheme = HTTPBearer(auto_error=auto_error)

    async def __call__(self, request: Request, *_):
        credentials = await self.auth_scheme(request)
        try:
            payload = decode_token(credentials.credentials)
        except ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Expired token")
        except JWTError:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid token")
        response = await self.app(request)
        return response
```

With : `app.add_middleware(JWTBearer)`

And there are so many possible exceptions that I have to handle.
If someone has an example or a reference? I found nothing about this.